# How does the client know which Icon to display on mouse over?

Tags: azerothcore

Whenever you're playing and you cross your mouse over any NPC an interaction icon should display. How does the Client know which icon to display and how does one change this?

An example: The sword icon on an enemy NPC or player.

Answer (score 1):

This can be changed in the `creature_template.IconName` field. A full list of available mouseovers can be found on the wiki https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/creature_template#iconname

Comment: Actually IconName is an unused field up until my latest PR. The way to change is using flags instead